# Differentiability of $ g(x)=f(2x)$ if $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$, $g(x)= f(2x-1)$ if $\frac{1}{2}< x \leq 1$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, contest-math

This is from an MCQ contest.

> Let  $f:[0,1] \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function.
>
> let $g:[0,1] \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ defined by: 
>   $$ g(x)=\begin{cases} f(2x) &  \text{if }0 \leq x \leq \dfrac{1}{2}\\ f(2x-1) & \text{if }\dfrac{1}{2}<  x \leq 1\end{cases} $$
>
> Which statement is true?
>
> - $1]$ $g$ is differentiable if and only if $f\biggl(0\biggr)=f\biggl(1\biggr)$ and $f'\biggl(0\biggr)=f'\biggl(1\biggr)$
> - $2]$ $g$ is differentiable if and only if $f\biggl(0\biggr)=f\biggl(\dfrac{1}{2}\biggr)$ and $f'\biggl(0\biggr)=f'\biggl(\dfrac{1}{2}\biggr)$
> - $3]$$g$ is differentiable if and only if $f\biggl(\dfrac{1}{2}\biggr)=f\biggl(1\biggr)$ and  $f'\biggl(\dfrac{1}{2}\biggr)=f'\biggl(1\biggr)$
> - $4]$$g$ is differentiable if and only if$f'\biggl(0\biggr)=f'\biggl(1\biggr)$.

My thoughts

note that $f$ is differentiable then $f$ is continuous

- $g$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ if and only if it's differentiable at   $\dfrac{1}{2}$

which means that

- $$\fbox{${\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^+}g(x)=g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\quad \text{: E1}}$}$$
- $$\fbox{$\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}g'(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^+}g'(x)=g'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\quad \text{: E2}$}$$

so

- \begin{align} \lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^+}g(x) =g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &\iff \lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}}f(2x)=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}}f(2x-1) =f\left(2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right)\\ &\iff f(1)=f(0)=f(1)\\ &\iff f(0)=f(1)\\ \end{align}
- \begin{align} \lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}g'(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^+}g'(x) =g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) &\iff \lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}}f'(2x)=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}}f'(2x-1) =f'\left(2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right)\\ &\iff f'(1)=f'(0)=f'(1)\\ &\iff f'(0)=f'(1)\\ \end{align}

beware about my old answer i should work with 
$$\lim_{x\to 0.5-}\frac{g(x)-g(0.5)}{x-\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{x\to 0.5+}\frac{g(x)-g(0.5)}{x-\frac{1}{2}}=g'(0.5)$$ instead of

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}g'(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^+}g'(x)=g'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\quad \text{: E2} $$

because we don't know nature of $f'$ is it continuos or not so

$$\lim_{x\to 0.5-}\frac{g(x)-g(0.5)}{x-\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{x\to 0.5+}\frac{g(x)-g(0.5)}{x-\frac{1}{2}}=g'(0.5)$$

which means 
$$\lim_{x\to 0.5-}\frac{f(2x)-f(1)}{x-\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{x\to 0.5+}\frac{f(2x-1)-f(1)}{x-\frac{1}{2}}=f'(1)$$

or

$$\lim_{x\to 0.5-}\frac{f(2x)-f(1)}{x-\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{x\to 0.5-}\frac{2( f(2x)-f(1))}{2x-1}=2 f'(1)$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0.5+}\frac{f(2x-1)-f(0)}{x-\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{x\to 0.5+}\frac{2( f(2x-1)-f(0))}{2x-1}=2 f'(0)$$

now i can relax i confirm that the statement number $1]$ is true

- Is my proof correct

Comment: I think you only need to worry about what happens to $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ when $x$ is close to $\frac12$, so you do not need to consider anything special about $g(0)$ or $g(1)$.  This leads to considering $f(x)$ when $x$ is close to $0$ and $1$ but you do not need anything special about $f(\frac12)$

Comment: Is the original question: _Which of 1], 2], 3] , 4] are necessary and sufficient conditions?_

Comment: All your questions apparently start with "This is from an MCQ contest." Could you at least tell us what "an MCQ contest" is? Looking up these words on the internet does not yield anything particularly useful.

Comment: c'est un concours sous forme d'un QCM

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_choice

Comment: Please no `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` in titles if you can avoid them (and you can).

Comment: @Did  didn't do it on purpose so next time i'll aviod it

Answer (score 1):

The function is basically a combination of two shrinked $f(x)$, so nothing at the two ends or interior of each half domain is worrisome.

You need and only need to prove:

1. $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0.5^-}g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0.5^+}g(x)$$
2. $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0.5^-}g'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0.5^+}g'(x)$$

Which means $f(0)=f(1)$ and $f'(0)=f'(1)$

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do

Comment: @Educ Sorry your working is a bit confusing because the latex code does not display properly. Can you edit that?

Comment: okay i will edit it

Comment: @Educ Thank you. Btw, it is a very prudent move to use first principle but I'm afraid it is not necessary in this case, especially given that it is a math contest. You should be able to tell $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0.5^+}g(x) = f(0)$ or anything like that on a glance.

Comment: yes because this kind of contest doesn't need to show the proof only the fast way to answer it

Comment: Check my update please

Comment: @Educ Yes that's perfectly right, but do make sure that you can do it in the fast way too in a contest.